# Camera extrinsics matrix blender

Tags: python, camera, coordinates

The camera object in blender python API has the variable `matrix_world`. I was hoping it would give the camera pose wrt to the world coordinate system but if you locate a camera in (0,0,0) with (0,0,0) rotation it gives you the 4x4 identity matrix which is not the correct transformation from a point in world coordinates to local camera coordinates as world cs and camera cs are not the same.

[image: blender cs]

Shouldn't the `matrix_world` reflect the 90º rotation about the **x** axis from world cs to camera cs?

Comment: Every object has a matrix_world. Whether it has a camera/mesh/etc attached doesn't change its matrix_world.

Comment: The camera "points" down its local $-Z$ axis.

Comment: Yeah the camera view is -*Z*. But still there needs to be a transformation between world cs and camera cs to define a camera pose no?

Comment: In example of camera at identity, and knowing its view is -Z locally, it points `Identity @ Vector((0, 0, -1))` or down the global Z axis.  Arbitrary, but logical (& common)  decision to make the image x, y dimension and the depth  z.  Basically I suppose I disagree with _"shouldn't"_ premise of question.